# Как вернуть 404 через apache2 закрыв таким образом папку

Tags: apache2

Как вернуть 404 через apache2 закрыв таким образом папку. Простой вопрос, не могу найти ответ...
Вот к примеру по такому же принципу, только чтобы не 403, а 404:

```
<Directory "/app/config">
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Comment: а зачем это все в принципе в корне сайта держать?

Comment: А вот такой прикол в cms-ок...